# Is there a way to escape colon in appsetting.json dictionary key in aspnetcore configuration?

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, appsettings

I have this provider dictionary in appsetting.json

```
  "AppSettings": {
      "Providers": {
         "http://localhost:5001": "Provider1",
         "http://localhost:5002": "Provider2"
      },
      "ArrayWorks": [
         "http://localhost:5001",
         "http://localhost:5002"
      ],
      "SoDoesColonInDictionaryValue": {
         "Provider1": "http://localhost:5001",
         "Provider2": "http://localhost:5002"
      }
   }
```

And the following throw exception because there's colon in the dictionary key.

`Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>()`

However, colon works fine as dictionary value, or array, just not dictionary key. 
 I read colon has special meaning in config, but there seems no way to escape.  Why?

Edit:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Providers { get; set; }
}
```

When debugging Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"), you get this

```
Key    AppSettings:Providers:http://localhost:5000
Value  Provider1
```

It was intended to be something like this

```
Key     AppSettings:Providers:http_//localhost_5000
```

But there seems no way to control how Configuration treat the :::

Comment: Is `AppSettings.Providers` a dictionary type `IDictionary<string, string>`?  Can you post your `AppSettings` class code.

Comment: @Brad  Thanks for the follow up, see Edit.

Comment: You don't have a section in your config called `AuthorizationProviders`.  Change the name in config and it should map correctly to `AppSettings`.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo in post only.  The issue is Configuration.GetSection insists on splitting by any and all colons in the key, and there's no way to control that since : is a valid json character.  So the question is, what if someone needs a dictionary of Urls.  I was hoping there's a way escape that into Configuration, like http\://localhost\:5000

Comment: You could look into creating your own config provider but I think working around this obscure limitation is the better way to go.  You could write your keys with underscores and then convert them to colons when they are read e.g. `services.Configure<AppSettings>(opts => {})` is not executed until first called upon by the `IOptions` service in your code.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121374/net-core-configuration-manager-reading-a-dictionary-where-one-key-has-a-colon

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:**
According to [aspnet/Configuration#792](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/792)

> Colons are reserved for special meaning in the keys, so they shouldn't
> be used as part of normal key values.

- This isn't supported and issue was closed.

---

- Not yet, Until now there is no escape colon character, Accourding to Microsoft Asp.net repository on github,  but there is an open [issue with #782](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/782) on the github repository which move it to [this backlog](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/milestone/5)

As a workaround you can reverse the key with the value in appsetting:AppSettings and correct it in code like the below:

```
"AppSettings": {
  "Providers": {
     "Provider1":"http://localhost:5001",
     "Provider2":"http://localhost:5002"
  },
  "ArrayWorks": [
     "http://localhost:5001",
     "http://localhost:5002"
  ],
  "SoDoesColonInDictionaryValue": {
     "Provider1": "http://localhost:5001",
     "Provider2": "http://localhost:5002"
  }
}
```

And in code make sure to reverse dictionary key and value as the below

```
 var result = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Providers")
               .GetChildren().ToDictionary(i=>i.Value,i=>i.Key);
      // result["http://localhost:5001"] return Provider1
      // result["http://localhost:5002"] return Provider2
```

Comment: Nice solution, flipping the key/value

Comment: This is not a solution if your values are complex objects, not just strings.