# .NET Core configuration manager, reading a dictionary where one key has a colon inside, gives an odd error message about the value, is this expected?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-configuration

The following program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            var configuration = builder.Build();
            var options = configuration.Get<Options>();
            foreach (var kvp in options.Values)
                Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}");
        }
    }

    internal class Options
    {
        public Dictionary<string, bool> Values { get; } = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    }
}
```

When given this `appsettings.json` file, runs perfectly:

```
{
    "Values": {
        "a": true,
        "b": false
    }
}
```

but change the `appsettings.json` contents to this:

```
{
    "Values": {
        "a:b": true,
        "b": false
    }
}
```

and I get this exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create instance of type 'System.Boolean' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.

stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, Object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindDictionary(Object dictionary, Type dictionaryType, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, Object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindProperty(PropertyInfo property, Object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindNonScalar(IConfiguration configuration, Object instance, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, Object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.Get[T](IConfiguration configuration, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at ConsoleApp3.Program.Main() in D:\Dev\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:line 15
```

What am I doing wrong? Note that having a colon in the key is perfectly legal json, but perhaps storing any odd dictionary in the appsettings.json file is not supported?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the colon? "a\:b"

Comment: No, let me try that

Comment: That is invalid json, as `\:` is not something that needs escaping. Adding two (which thus means I now just added a backslash to the key, in addition to the colon) gets me back to the exception.

Comment: `When the file is read into configuration, unique keys are created to maintain the original hierarchical data structure of the configuration source. The sections and keys are flattened with the use of a colon (:) to maintain the original structure:` Your colon is going to break the structure of appsettings file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#hierarchical-configuration-data

Comment: I see, ok, then I will just have to move the paths to a property instead, I was configuring paths and whether they were enabled, guess I cannot use the path as a key then. Thanks. Care to leave it as an answer that I can accept?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I'm doing a little more reading up on the topic to make sure there are no other ways around it. I'll post something in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core: Hierarchical configuration data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#hierarchical-configuration-data)

> The Configuration API is capable of maintaining hierarchical configuration data by flattening the hierarchical data with the use of a delimiter in the configuration keys.
>
> When the file is read into configuration, unique keys are created to maintain the original hierarchical data structure of the configuration source. The sections and keys are flattened with the use of a colon (:) to maintain the original structure

That means that in the following *appsettings.json* file

```
{
    "Values": {
        "a:b": true,
        "b": false
    }
}
```

The keys would be flattened to

- **Values:a:b**
- **Values:b**

which is going to break the structure of settings file when the [`ConfigurationBinder.BindDictionary`](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/d469707ab18eef7ed0002f00175a9ad5b0f36250/src/Config.Binder/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L385) tries to bind the `Dictionary<string, bool>` property in the `Options`

Also referencing this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/792)

> Colons are reserved for special meaning in the keys, so they shouldn't be used as part of normal key values.